# Is there a design-pattern that addresses creation of the same product in multiple different ways (requiring pipeline-like pre-creation steps)

Tags: design-patterns, factory-pattern, abstract-factory, factory-method

I am currently working on a machine learning project and would like my Python program to be able to process/convert measurement data from various measurement data formats into a PyTorch compatible dataset class. This essentially means that I need to extract samples and labels from these measurements so that I can instantiate my dataset class.

**Right now:** I am mainly using a single `libraryA` which provides all functions I need to load and preprocess the data. To extract the samples and labels as needed I have to follow several processing steps which is why I decided to encapsulate that logic in a simple factory class.

**My concern is:** What if I need to handle a data format that is not supported by `libraryA` but by another `libraryB`. That `libraryB`, however, has a very different approach on how to extract the samples and labels and requires different processing steps.

**My initial thought**: Use an abstract factory or a factory method to create the dataset object and let the subclass decide how to do it. But, despite that I am not following the intent of abstract factories / factory method as stated by the GoF (I always want the same single product), the signatures of the abstract methods won't match because the libraries require very different inputs.

**My question:** Is there a suitable Design-Pattern that standardizes the creation of the same product with very different pre-creation steps? 
Or should I stick to concrete simple factories that are tightly coupled to the library (e.g. `LibADatasetFactory` and `LibBDatasetFactory`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a suitable Design-Pattern that standardizes the creation of the same product with very different pre-creation steps?

If the same product should be created but by using various approaches or strategies, then Strategy pattern can be used. So one creation strategy will use `libraryA`, while another strategy will use `libraryB` to create an object. As wiki says about [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> In computer programming, the strategy pattern (also known as the
> policy pattern) is a behavioral software design pattern that enables
> selecting an algorithm at runtime. Instead of implementing a single
> algorithm directly, code receives run-time instructions as to which in
> a **family of algorithms to use**

Let me show an example via C#.

We will create `Person` by various libraries:

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an abstraction of creation of `Person` that will use various libraries:

```
public interface IPersonCreationByLibrary 
{
    Person Create();
}
```

And this is a concrete implementation of abstraction to create `Person` by various libaries:

```
public class PersonCreationByLibraryA : IPersonCreationByLibrary
{
    
    public Person Create()
    {
        // use here libraryA to create a person
        return new Person() { Name = "Person A"};
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class PersonCreationByLibraryB : IPersonCreationByLibrary
{

    public Person Create()
    {
        // use here libraryB to create a person
        return new Person() { Name = "Person B" };
    }
}
```

And this is types of libraries that can be used to create `Person`:

```
public enum Library
{
    A, 
    B
}
```

And this is factory to create strategies of what library should be used to create a `Person`:

```
public class PersonCreationByLibraryFactory
{
    private Dictionary<Library, IPersonCreationByLibrary> _personByLibrary = 
    new () 
    {
        { Library.A, new PersonCreationByLibraryA() },
        { Library.B, new PersonCreationByLibraryB() }
    };

    public IPersonCreationByLibrary GetInstanceByLibrary(Library library) => 
        _personByLibrary[library];
}
```

and this is method which shows how to use the above code:

```
Person CreateByLibrary(Library library) 
{
    PersonCreationByLibraryFactory personCreationByLibraryFactory = 
        new PersonCreationByLibraryFactory();
    IPersonCreationByLibrary personCreationByLibrary =  
        personCreationByLibraryFactory.GetInstanceByLibrary(library);
    return personCreationByLibrary.Create();
}
```

And the above code can be run like this:

```
Person person = CreateByLibrary(Library.A); // OUTPUT: "Person A"
```